# Issue with OpenAL on iPhone - using alcOpenDevice on two apps

Tags: ios, iphone, openal

I have a problem I thought I'd ask about here.

I implemented OpenAL in two of my apps.

Problem is if one app is running in the background (i.e. I launched it, then pressed the HOME button to launch the other one) - when I launch the other one `alcOpenDevice` fails. It returns:

> 2013-12-04 11:39:23.866 Safari Puzzle[4132:4803] 11:39:23.866 ERROR: 185: Error creating aggregate audio device: 'nope'
>
> 2013-12-04 11:39:23.867 Safari Puzzle[4132:4803] 11:39:23.867 WARNING: 219: The input device is 0x39; 'AppleHDAEngineInput:1B,0,1,0:1'
>
> 2013-12-04 11:39:23.867 Safari Puzzle[4132:4803] 11:39:23.867 WARNING: 223: The output device is 0x2f; 'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,1:0'
>
> 2013-12-04 11:39:23.868 Safari Puzzle[4132:4803] 11:39:23.868 ERROR: 398: error 'nope'
>
> 2013-12-04 11:39:23.869 Safari Puzzle[4132:4503] 11:39:23.869 ERROR: 398: error -66680
>
> 2013-12-04 11:39:23.869 Safari Puzzle[4132:70b] 11:39:23.869 ERROR: >aurioc> 783: failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch, 44100 Hz, Int16, inter> inf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Int16, inter>)

Any help, anyone ?

---

EDIT:

Could be it is just the simulator - On a real device both apps work ok...